# php & js dynamic creation of auto populated dropdown lists

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a script which fills the second combobox with the value of the first one. But it is not quite what I want to do. I want to fill the second combobox with the result of a SQL query based on the item which was selected in the first combobox.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectDropdown(){
        var dropdownValue=document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        $('option[value=st]').text(dropdownValue);
    }
</script>
```

first combobox:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="selectDropdown()">
    <option value="dd">--take an option--</option>
    <?
    $standard = Env::value('standard');
    if (!$status)
        $statement = "select code from standard";
    foreach ($db->query($statement )->fetchall() as $row)
        echo "<option".($row == $standard ? ' selected ' : '').">$row[0]</option>";
    ?>
</select>
```

and the second one in which I want to show the result of the query: `$q= select request.code from request inner join standard on ( request.standard_id=standard.id) where standard.code=$st`.

```
<select name='st' class='txt'>
  <option value="st"><? echo $st; ?></option>
</select>
```

Can anyone give me a hint where I should put query execution? Or just point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use pure js to get value of dropdown, and then use jQuery to get option's text value?

Comment: lack of experience and knowledge :( could you provide me with proper article or tutorial about things I should lern?

Comment: If you wish to run a query then you must use server side code which requires an ajax call.  See this article which does something similar. http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's ajax call to make a request to the server each time when first dropdown selection has been changed. On the server side create a script which will receive that request and return corresponding records for 2nd dropdown in JSON format, which then can be easily processed by javascript. For using ajax see this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It will be like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://domain.com/path/to/script.php",
    data: value_of_selected_item_from_first_dropdown,
    success: function(response) {
        // Set 2nd dropdown values to those received via response
    }
    dataType: "json",
});
```